# How can I tab between two variables in this print statement to align table? see code below using 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

How can I tab between two variables in this print statement? The code is straight from a textbook example but it's not working on the final print statement. It just prints out '\t' instead of tabbing. Is this a data type issue?

The code below uses loop to display table showing 1-10 & their squares

```
print('Number \t Square')
print('--------------')
for number in range (1,11):
    square=number**2
    print(number, '\t', square)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting (indenting) is essential in Python.  The code works fine when you format it like this:

```
print('Number \t Square')
print('--------------')
for number in range (1,11):
    square=number**2
    print(number, '\t', square)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
left_width = len("Number")
right_width = len("Square")
print('Number \t Square')
print('--------------')
for number in range(1, 11):
    square = number ** 2
    left_text = str(number).ljust(left_width)
    right_text = str(square).rjust(right_width)
    print(f"{left_text} \t {right_text}")
```

Srings in python have 'ljust', 'rjust' & 'center' methods that come into handy for similar occasions.

Comment: Thank you so very much

Comment: Houdini211, If you are satisfied with the solution then please check to accept it and click on the up arrow.  That is how members are able to accumulate reputation points needed to unlock features. Thank you!